# hover not working correctly when using different kinds of subplots in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to generate a plotly-figure that contains one [Scattermapbox](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scattermapbox.html) and multiple other types of plots (in this case line plots generated with [Scatter](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Scatter.html)). Everything looks good, but when I hover over the line plots, no hover info is displayed.

If I do not create the Scattermapbox-plot, the hover over the line plots works correctly (in the minimal example below you can test this by un-commenting the `fig.show()` and `exit()` lines).

Am I doing something wrong and/or is there any way to fix this?

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go


fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[
        [{'rowspan':2, 'type' :'mapbox'},{'type' : 'scatter'}],
        [None,{'type' : 'scatter'}],
    ],
    print_grid=True,
)

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y1,
    ),
    row=1, col=2,
)


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x,
        y=y2,
    ),
    row=2, col=2,
)

# UNCOMMENT THESE TWO LINES TO TEST WITHOUT SCATTERMAPBOX
#fig.show()
#exit()

coordinates = {
    'Berlin' : (52.5200, 13.4050),
    'Munich' : (48.1351, 11.5820),
    'Hamburg' : (53.5488, 9.9872),
    'Frankfurt' : (50.1109, 8.6821),
    'Dresden' : (51.0504, 13.7373),
}

z, lat, lon, names = zip(*[
    (i,v[0],v[1],k) for i,(k,v) in enumerate(coordinates.items())])
    
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lat = lat,
        lon = lon,
        mode = 'markers+text',
        text = names,
        below = '',
        marker_size=12,
        marker_color=z,
        name = 'town',
    ),
    col=1, row=1,
)

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=0, t=40, b=40))
    
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox1=dict(
        zoom=4, style='carto-positron',
        center={k:v for k,v in zip(['lat','lon'],coordinates['Frankfurt'])}, 
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since scattertermapbox uses layers provided by mapbox, I think I need to specify the names of layers that can be provided and a free API token. See the reference for details. The following code will create a subplot containing a map.

```
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapbox_access_token = open("./mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[
        [{'rowspan':2, 'type' :'mapbox'},{'type' : 'scatter'}],
        [None,{'type' : 'scatter'}],
    ],
    print_grid=True,
)

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y1,), row=1, col=2,)


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y2,), row=2, col=2,)

coordinates = {
    'Berlin' : (52.5200, 13.4050),
    'Munich' : (48.1351, 11.5820),
    'Hamburg' : (53.5488, 9.9872),
    'Frankfurt' : (50.1109, 8.6821),
    'Dresden' : (51.0504, 13.7373),
}

z, lat, lon, names = zip(*[
    (i,v[0],v[1],k) for i,(k,v) in enumerate(coordinates.items())])
    
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
        lat = lat,
        lon = lon,
        mode = 'markers+text',
        text = names,
        below = '',
        marker_size=12,
        marker_color=z,
        name = 'town',
    ),
    col=1, row=1,
)

fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=20, r=0, t=40, b=40))
    
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox1=dict(
        zoom=4,
        style='light',
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        center={k:v for k,v in zip(['lat','lon'],coordinates['Frankfurt'])}, 
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not quite sure whether you misunderstood the question: I don't have problems displaying the map, the problem is that I don't get hover information of the line plots, when the map is displayed.